# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of async function without a catch block

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubectl

I am running mongo-express instance on my local docker hub container by using kubectl, and when I start deployment I am getting an Exception in Mongo-Express instance.
Below is my mongo-express.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        env:
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef: 
                name: mongodb-secret
                key: mongo-root-username  
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef: 
                name: mongodb-secret
                key: mongo-root-password 
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef: 
                name: mongodb-configmap
                key: database_url
```

and below is my mongo-deployment.yaml file,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef: 
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username 
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef: 
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports: 
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 27017
```

similarly i have configmap and secret file as well
However, when I apply both files I get below Exception on docker container,

```
Welcome to mongo-express
------------------------



(node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://root:root@mongodb-service:27017/"
(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb-service:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out
    at connectionFailureError (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:342:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:483:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
    at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:483:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Could anyone advice what to do?

Comment: @Wytrzymały Wiktor yes, i have accepted first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the community.

There is a small mistake in your service for `mongo db`. Listening port should be `27017` instead of `80`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports: 
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

This allowed my `mongo express` to connect to database:

```
kubectl logs mongo-express-yyyyyyyyy-xxxxx
Welcome to mongo-express
------------------------


(node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!
```

Comment: Thanks @moonkotte, this solution helped me

Comment: Why does the `port` need to be the same as the `targetPort`? In my understanding, a Service map any incoming `port` to a `targetPort`.

Comment: For example, if I change the `port` to 27018 then it is still working.

Answer (score 0):

Please try if there is an option in mongo-express yaml file, by adding a dependency variable. In docker it works when I add depends_on in yaml of mongo-express.

```
depends_on:
      - mongodb-service
```

mongodb-service I think is the name of the service you have used in mongodb yaml.